# Comma seprated Input string

Tags: sql, oracle, split

```
SELECT DISTINCT REGEXP_SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(:InputString),'[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) AS  VEA_VALIDATION_INFOLET_PARAMS FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(:InputString), '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL;
```

Using this statement getting error When i trying to pass more than 4000 characters.

> "ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested"

```
SELECT DISTINCT REGEXP_SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(:InputString),'[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) AS  VEA_VALIDATION_INFOLET_PARAMS FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(:InputString), '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL;
```

I expect comma seprated data.

Comment: "*When i trying to pass more than 4000 characters.*" - you simply can't. A single string constant cannot be longer than 4000 byte in Oracle.

Comment: you can try the solution by asktom: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9529975800346436673